# Configuring one-to-many foreign key to a non primary key property

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

This maybe an easy question but I didn't manage to figure it out after hours of reading Microsoft documentation. I have following 2 models in my DB (I simplified them for better understanding):

```
public class Schedule
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public string Role { get; set; }
}

public class Roles
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public string RoleDisplay { get; set; }
}
```

I need to set up `Role` string from `Schedule` model as a foreign key with one-to-many relation to `RoleDisplay` key in `Roles` model. So in `Schedule` we can have a lot of records with `Role` cell pointing to the `Roles` table.

If it was regular Id key I would add

```
public Roles Roles { get; set; }
```

to `Schedule` and EF would automatically generate corresponding `RoleID` column in the `Schedule` table.

The issue is that I'm not dealing with primary key and the key naming convention doesn't match standard

```
<TableName><ColumnName>
```

I heard that this can be set up in Fluent API, something like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Schedule>()
    .HasOne()
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey();
```

but I didn't figure out what needs to be put in brackets for each statement.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Added an answer. See it it solves your issue.

Comment: @atiyar sorry, was busy testing other stuff. This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have any navigation property on either entity, you have to use the generic version `HasOne<Roles>()` to indicate which table the foreign-key refers to. Once that is clear to EF, you don't need to pass anything to `WithMany()`. Try the following -

1. Declare `RoleDisplay` as an alternate-key on `Roles` -

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Roles>(e =>
{
    e.HasKey(p => p.Id);
    e.HasAlternateKey(p => p.RoleDisplay);
});
```

2. While configuring the foreign-key on `Schedule`, specify which key on `Roles` it should target -

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Schedule>(e =>
{
    e.HasKey(p => p.Id);
});
modelBuilder.Entity<Schedule>()
    .HasOne<Roles>()
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.Role)
    .HasPrincipalKey(p => p.RoleDisplay);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I know this isn't part of the OP's question, but what is the `Data Annotation` way?